# Unable to mount existing folder in docker with Linux

Tags: linux, docker, rstudio, volume, mount

I am running a [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/) docker container in Alpine Linux and would like to mount an existing folder under `/home/myFolder` with some data for the container to read from and write to.

I tried mounting the folder as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382793/how-to-set-up-a-data-volume-within-docker) but I don't see the folder listed in RStudio. Here are a couple of commands I tried with no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/myFolder:/myFolder/ rocker/rstudio

docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/myFolder rocker/rstudio
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why is this question down voted? The need to share a Unix (or Windows for that matter) folder to docker containers so that one can populate data frames in R is development related and certainly relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to clarify what you are trying to do:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/myFolder:/myFolder/ rocker/rstudio
```

With the command above, you are mounting your host folder `/home/myFolder` inside the docker container in folder `/myFolder/`. To see if your folder was mounted inside the container try:

```
docker exec -it <name-of-the-container> bash
ls -la /myFolder
```

The other thing that you are trying to do:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v /home/myFolder rocker/rstudio
```

is create a volume, or use a already existing volume and attach it to the container. While [bind](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) mounts are dependent on the directory structure of the host machine, [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) are completely managed by Docker

Comment: Thank you @Luminance for the explanation. I understand better now!